# how to combine a subscription to not get "Opc.Ua.ServiceResultException: 'BadTooManySubscriptions': error in C# - OCP UA

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I am having to write a small HMI program in c#. I have about 200 tags to subscribe. I know that adding a subscription to each tag will error after 5 subscriptions (in my case the server is running on a Siemens s7-1200 PLC)

I am just learning c# and I know the answer is to combine my subscriptions in to an array, but I cannot find exactly how to do it. I have exhausted Youtube and other resources which never seem to actually show the code to make the array.

I know this code is wrong, but it shows what my goal is. If I comment out all but 5 of the following lines, I get the tag data I need..... I just need to learn how to combine all of the tags in to an array of items and use one subscription.

```
        try
        {

        myClient.AddSubscription("IDODChuck1", "ns=4;i=203", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("IDODChuck2", "ns=4;i=204", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMI_High_Thresh_Chuck1", "ns=4;i=9", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Calculated1VOLTS", "ns=4;i=148", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Calculated2VOLTS", "ns=4;i=150", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Arrow2", "ns=4;i=149", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("B", "ns=4;i=150", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMI_High_Thresh_Chuck1", "ns=4;i=9", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Calculated1VOLTS", "ns=4;i=154", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Chuck1Nominal", "ns=4;i=2", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Chuck2Nominal", "ns=4;i=3", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CurHMIMeasureDiaLPS1", "ns=4;i=4", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CurHMIMeasureDiaLPS2", "ns=4;i=5", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CurHMIMeasureRadLPS1", "ns=4;i=6", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CurHMIMeasureRadLPS2", "ns=4;i=7", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CurrentChuckScreen", "ns=4;i=8", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClmpHighThreshArrowChuck1", "ns=4;i=9", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClmpHighThreshArrowChuck2", "ns=4;i=10", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClmpLowThreshArrowChuck1", "ns=4;i=11", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClmpLowThreshArrowChuck2", "ns=4;i=12", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMICloseEOSLineChuck1", "ns=4;i=13", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMICloseEOSLineChuck2", "ns=4;i=14", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClampHighThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=15", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClampHighThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=16", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClampLowThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=17", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClampLowThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=18", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIUnClampThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=19", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIUnClampThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=20", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("PlusClampHighThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=35", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("PlusClampHighThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=36", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("PlusClampLowThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=37", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("PlusClampLowThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=38", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("PlusUnClampThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=39", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("PlusUnClampThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=40", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ApplyTolereanceLPS1", "ns=4;i=41", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ApplyTolereanceLPS2", "ns=4;i=42", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("MinusClampHighThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=49", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("MinusClampHighThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=50", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("MinusClampLowThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=51", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("MinusClampLowThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=52", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CLOSEEOSONLPS1", "ns=4;i=55", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("CLOSEEOSONLPS2", "ns=4;i=56", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ENBLClmpConfChuck1", "ns=4;i=57", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ENBLClmpConfChuck2", "ns=4;i=58", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ENBLUnClmpConfChuck1", "ns=4;i=69", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ENBLUnClmpConfChuck2", "ns=4;i=70", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("LPS1Online", "ns=4;i=79", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("LPS2Online", "ns=4;i=81", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("MinusUnClampThreshChuck1", "ns=4;i=103", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("MinusUnClampThreshChuck2", "ns=4;i=104", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ChangeTexttoEOSLPS1", "ns=4;i=123", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ChangeTexttoEOSLPS2", "ns=4;i=124", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClampLightChuck1", "ns=4;i=127", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIClampLightChuck2", "ns=4;i=128", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIOTLightChuck1", "ns=4;i=131", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIOTLightChuck2", "ns=4;i=132", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIUnClampLightChuck1", "ns=4;i=133", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIUnClampLightChuck2", "ns=4;i=134", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("LowClmpHigherthanHighChuck1", "ns=4;i=137", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("LowClmpHigherthanHighChuck2", "ns=4;i=138", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ShowCANNOTTEACHmsg", "ns=4;i=139", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ShowTeachUnclamLPS1", "ns=4;i=140", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("ShowTeachUnclamLPS2", "ns=4;i=141", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("TeachIDODSameTimeLPS1", "ns=4;i=142", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("TeachIDODSameTimeLPS2", "ns=4;i=143", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Calculated1VOLTS", "ns=4;i=154", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("Calculated2VOLTS", "ns=4;i=155", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("RetentiveMemoryMaintUnclmpClampChuck1", "ns=4;i=191", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("RetentiveMemoryMaintUnclmpOTChuck1", "ns=4;i=192", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("RetentiveMemoryMaintUnclmpClampChuck2", "ns=4;i=193", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("RetentiveMemoryMaintUnclmpOTChuck2", "ns=4;i=194", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIODCLMPNOMINPUTLPS1", "ns=4;i=195", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIODCLMPNOMINPUTLPS2", "ns=4;i=196", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIODUNCLMPNOMINPUTLPS1", "ns=4;i=197", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIODUNCLMPNOMINPUTLPS2", "ns=4;i=198", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIIDCLMPNOMINPUTLPS1", "ns=4;i=199", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIIDCLMPNOMINPUTLPS2", "ns=4;i=200", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIIDUNCLMPNOMINPUTLPS1", "ns=4;i=201", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("HMIIDUNCLMPNOMINPUTLPS2", "ns=4;i=202", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("IDODChuck1", "ns=4;i=203", SubCallback);
        myClient.AddSubscription("IDODChuck2", "ns=4;i=204", SubCallback);

        }
        catch (Exception) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a separate Subscription for each tag.

Create one Subscription and add each tag as a MonitoredItem to that Subscription.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. As I said, I know that code is wrong and that I need one subscription, but I cannot find anywhere to learn exactly how to make that array. I included all of that wrong code to show the tags I wanted to include in the one subscription I know I need to use. I am fairly familiar with making and using arrays, but , being very new to C#, I cant get the syntax correct. I was hoping to find a link to be educated.